# Creating a zoomable view that overlaps other views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-relativelayout

I am trying to create a view in which there is a title at the top, an image in the middle, and a row of buttons at the bottom. I would like the image to be overlaid on top of all other views so that when I zoom in on the image, the image can take up the entire screen. I have it mostly working but only on smaller images. The problem I am facing is that when I get a large (tall) image, the image is initialized to the entire height of the view and my title/buttons are hidden behind the image.

How can I allow my image to be zoomed to the entirety of the view but also initialize the image size so that my buttons/title is not covered when a user arrives to this view?

I've tried wrap_content for height of the image and that only limits the size of my zoom image.
**Example of image that gives me good results:**

[image]

**Example of image that is too tall that gives bad results:**

[image]

**My layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBgBlackTintDarkest"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <!-- Submission title/subreddit info -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_display_title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/big_display_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Title about something random that we found on reddit while browsing yesterday"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            />

        <!--subreddit name-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp">

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/big_display_subreddit"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="/r/subreddit"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                 />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_white_chat"
            android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_comments"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_white_upvote_medium"
            android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_upvote"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_white_downvote_medium"
            android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_downvote"/>

        <!-- overflow -->


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_white_overflow_small"
            android:id="@+id/big_display_snack_bar_overflow"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.github.piasy.biv.view.BigImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/big_image_viewer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use constraint layout and make use of guidelines.

Comment: Can you show me an example please?

Comment: [Reference Link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018)